# Evaluate polynomial at specific value

Tags: functions, polynomials

1. Suppose that $P(x)=\dfrac{x-2}{x-2}$. Does $P(2)=1$ or is $P(2)$ undefined?
2. Similarly, assume that $P(x)=\dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}$. Does $P(2)=4$ or is $P(2)$ undefined?

Updating :
Please if anyone can let me know which of the case's step is mathematically wrong or All are correct.

1. Find the value of $\frac{20^2-20^2}{400-400}$.

Answer:

Case 1:$ \frac{20(20-20)}{20^2-20^2}=\frac{20(20-20)}{(20+20)(20-20)}$. Now, this factor $(20-20)$ cancels out. $=\frac{20}{40} = \frac{1}{2}$

OR Case 2:$ \frac{20^2-20^2}{400-400}=\frac{20^2-20^2}{20^2-20^2}=1$

OR Case: 3 Not Defined

OR Case 4: $\frac{20^2-20^2}{20(20-20)} =\frac{(20+20)(20-20)}{20(20-20)}$. Now, this factor $(20-20)$ cancels out. $=\frac{40}{20 }=2$

Comment: What do you do? We can't divide by $0$ in any case.

Comment: $400-400=0$ so case 3 is correct since $0/0$ is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases it's not defined because the domain in both cases it's $\mathbb R\setminus\{2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that in the second case

$$P(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}\underset{x\neq 2}{=}x+2$$

and in the first case

$$P(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-2}\underset{x\neq 2}{=}1$$

As setting $x=2$ causes the denominator to be zero, $P(2)$ is undefined. This is known as a hole or removable discontinuity.